# Add root element to xml string and parse for data in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I would like to add root element to my xml string and then parse the data.

I have not well formatted xml string which throws an exception while parsing, So i would like to add root element to my xml string and then send it to `Document doc = dBuilder.parse( iSource );` for parsing. So can anyone suggest me how to go about it ?

**Error:**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
```

**xml string:**

```
System.out.println(StdOut );
```

prints as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <transaction id="1">
   <header>
       <method>Agent007</method>
       <subclass>ERROR</subclass>
   </header>
   <data>
      <incoming_message>xxxxxxxxx</incoming_message>
      <errorcode>FAIL</errorcode>
      <errortext>There are no Integration Services </errortext>
      <errordetail>exceptions.ServiceNotFoundException</errordetail>
   </data>
</transaction>
```

**code i used:**

```
public String parseStatusXML( String StdOut )
    {
        String stdOutResult = null;            

        try
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();          

            InputSource iSource = new InputSource();
            iSource.setCharacterStream( new StringReader( StdOut ) );

            Document doc = dBuilder.parse( iSource );

            NodeList subClassNode = doc.getElementsByTagName( "subclass" );
            Element element = (Element) subClassNode.item( 0 );

            if ( getCharacterDataFromElement( element ).equalsIgnoreCase( "ERROR" ) )
            {

                System.out.println( " getCharacterDataFromElement( element ) : "
                                + getCharacterDataFromElement( element ) );
                NodeList dataNode = doc.getElementsByTagName( "data" );
                for ( int i = 0; i < dataNode.getLength(); i++ )
                {
                    Element dataElement = (Element) dataNode.item( i );

                    NodeList errorCodeNode = dataElement.getElementsByTagName( "errorcode" );
                    Element errorCodeElement = (Element) errorCodeNode.item( 0 );

                    NodeList errorTextNode = dataElement.getElementsByTagName( "errortext" );
                    Element errorTextElement = (Element) errorTextNode.item( 0 );

                    NodeList errorDetailNode = dataElement.getElementsByTagName( "errordetail" );
                    Element errorDetailElement = (Element) errorDetailNode.item( 0 );

                    // passing ERROR flag
                    stdOutResult = getCharacterDataFromElement( element );

                }

            }
            else if ( getCharacterDataFromElement( element ).equalsIgnoreCase( "OK" ) )
            {
                stdOutResult = getCharacterDataFromElement( element );

            }

        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stdOutResult;

    }

public static String getCharacterDataFromElement( Element e )
    {
        Node child = e.getFirstChild();
        if ( child instanceof CharacterData )
        {
            CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
            return cd.getData();
        }
        return "?";

    }
```

Comment: Please, if you're going to post a question, ask a question.

Comment: i'd recommend trying the jdk's built in parser instead of using xerces directly.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of posting a more "hacky" solution, I'd suggest using string manipulation (quick and dirty, but effective) to add in the root tags. So essentially, read the file in as a string, find the starting tag before which you want to insert the root, use "replace" to insert the root tag, then concatenate the string back together (along with a closing tag, of course). So for instance:

```
    // Open up the file
    File file = new File(filePath);

    // Read it in as a string
    String fileToString = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);

    // Find the location of the first "<dataset"
    int locOfFirstTransaction = fileToString.indexOf("<transaction");

    // Get the first "section" and concatenate the root tag to it
    String firstPart = fileToString.substring(0, locOfFirstTransaction);
    firstPart = firstPart.concat("\n\t<rootTag>\n\t"); 

    // Define the remaining part of the string and concatenate the firstPart to it
    String lastPart = fileToString.substring(locOfFirstTransaction, fileToString.length());
    fileToString = firstPart.concat(lastPart);

    // Replace the closing tag for rootTag
    fileToString = fileToString.replace("</transaction", "\t</rootTag>\n</currentscreen");

    // Finally, write this out to a new file
    File resultFile = new File(newFilePath);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(resultFile);
    fw.write(fileToString);
    fw.close();
```

That should insert in the root tag. There are much better ways, specifically parsing using DocumentBuilder, but this will get you going in a pinch. Hope this helps!